# How to use a dynamic connection string with blob binding in Azure function

Tags: azure-functions

I know the azure function support dynamic binding with IBinder, with it I can create a BlobAttribut with dynamic path, but the connection property of this attribut always be processed as the name of configure item.
How can I specify a connnection string directly (an SAS token) to the BlobAttribute in the run time?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported. To begin with, you cannot use a SAS token with a blob binding (you need to provide a connection string with full permissions, see GitHub issues [#199](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/199) and [#468](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/468)).

You won't get the goodness of bindings, but you can directly using the Azure Storage SDK instead.

Comment: Thanks, what's the advantage that using binding over the Azure storage SDK? Or I jsut want to learn that Azure function why provide the storage bidning when we can access storage with Azure Storage SDK?

Comment: Trigger bindings offer unique functionality that referencing an SDK doesn't have (although you could argue that an Event Grid trigger binding is sufficient for most trigger integration points). Input/output bindings are mainly used for easy integration with other (Azure) services, which are very common scenarios. Bindings opt you in to having the azure functions runtime manage the SDK for you.